# Is it possible to force a modification to contacts on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I am developing an application in which I will modify the contents of some Contacts. For now, I am able to lookup a contact and edit it with the following code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY,"XXXXXXXX");
i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,"987654321");
startActivity(i);
```

When I select a contact, I see the field Company and Phone automatically filled. This is as to be expected. It is then, that the user will decide to save it or not. I would want it to be automatic. As soon, as I select a contact, it is automatically edited and saved.

I have tried to find a way, but in vain. Do you think it is possible and how? I tried using the intent with EXTRA FORCE CREATE but it did not work.

Comment: i also doing the same thing but i dont know how to done the modification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
            String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
            ctx.getContentResolver().update(uri, contentValues, where conditon here,null);
```

Hope it Helps!!